# VBA: Scraping exact elements from HTMLTable

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Please can you help me to understand how to find tags `a` in `Table` with class name `bptable`?

I receive `Object does not support this method` and I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
Sub ListVideosOnPage(VidCatName As String, VidCatURL As String)

Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim VidRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim VidInnerRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement


Dim VidRows As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim VidInnerRows As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection


Dim VidInnerCatID As Integer

XMLReq.Open "GET", VidCatURL, False
XMLReq.send

If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
        Exit Sub
End If

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
Set XMLReq = Nothing

Set VidRows = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("bptable")
Set VidInnerRows = ***VidRows***.getElementsByTagName("a")
   With VidRows
        For VidInnerCatID = 2 To VidInnerRows.Length
                    Set VidInnerRow = VidInnerRows(VidInnerCatID)                                                
                    'Debug.Print                      
        Next VidInnerCatID
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are using `getElementsByClassName` so I think `VidRows` will be a HTML Element Collection, so I think you'll need `VidRows(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use css selectors as generally a faster selector method and reduces the loops so lower complexity. You loop a single nodeList.

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As long
Set nodeList = HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll(".bptable a")
For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
    Debug.Print nodeList.item(i).innerText
Next
```

The `.` in front of `bptable` is a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors); the space after is a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/descendant_combinator), and the final `a` is a [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/type_selectors). It says select `a` tag elements who parent has class `bptable`.

I am printing to the immediate window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much! css selectors work great. As it turns out, I should find all ("bptable td")  and nodeList.Item(i).innerText shows me right content. But also I need to find children of  ("bptable td") with tag a and find .getAttribute("href"). Could you tell me how to find children of ("bptable td") ?

Comment: you want the hrefs as well? Or just the hrefs from what you have? Set nodeList = HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll(".bptable [href]") then loop and use nodeList.item(i).href

Comment: I need hrefs from what i have. if I use (".bptable [href]") I get all hrefs. On the other hand, if I use ("bptable td") and then Debug.Print nodeList.Item(i).getAttribute("href") I get null. I think I can solve it tomorrow. Thank you one more time. You really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.getElementsByTagName("a")` on collection of elements you can either use `VidRows(0)` or try a `for loop` to get individual element in order to apply `.getElementsByTagName("a")` on them. I would opt for a `for loop` to serve the purpose. The following is one such way to get the content.

```
Sub ListVideosOnPage(VidCatName As String, VidCatURL As String)

    Dim XMLReq As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim VidInnerRows As Object
    Dim R As Long

    XMLReq.Open "GET", VidCatURL, False
    XMLReq.send

    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If

    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
    Set XMLReq = Nothing

    For Each VidInnerRows In HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("bptable")
        With VidInnerRows.getElementsByTagName("a")
            If .Length Then R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
    Next VidInnerRows
End Sub
```